# PHP dynamically creating variable to split array

Tags: php, arrays, list, variables, dynamic

```
<?php
    $my_array = array("hello","world","howareu");
    $c = count($my_array);

    for($i=0;$i<=$c;$i++){
        $v = '$var'.$i;
        $splited = list($v) = $my_array;
    }
?>
```

**input:**
$my_array

**But expected output:**

if I `echo $var0, $var1, $var2;`

```
hello, world, howareu
```

**How to create dynamic PHP variables based upon the array count and then convert them into a list as a string?**

Comment: If anyone isn't clear about this, let me know so that I can post some more inputs.

Comment: Please, add more info. Not clear what you really need. Add input and output you want to receive

Comment: But where in your examples are you using the echo $splited. Also, the documentation supplied tells us that list() is returning the defined array. Echo'ing an array is not possible, use var_dump instead to see the content. 
the var_dump ( iterated 4 times due to the <= in the for-loop ) is showing the same content as it is actually the $my_array every time.

Comment: @kovpack - Please check the revised post.

Comment: Take a look on my answer. It seems to be what you need. Variable variables is what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need list for that. $$ will suit you perfectly.

```
$my_array = array("hello", "world", "howareu");

foreach ($my_array as $key => $val)
{
    $a = 'var'.$key;
    $$a = $val;
}

echo $var0,", ", $var1,", " $var2;
```

Take a look here - [Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

**Added:** 
or if you need `count` and `for`

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($my_array); $i++)
{
    $a = 'var'.$i;
    $$a = $my_array[$i];
}

echo $var0,", ", $var1,", " $var2;
```

Of course, this line `echo $var0,", ", $var1,", " $var2;` sucks and looks like crap :) But in order to receive EXACTLY what you want, you need to modify variables, output like I've wrote, or use some function like `implode` with grue `', '`.

**Updated:**

But if you need just that output, why not to use simple `implode(', ', $my_array)` :)

Comment: Yes, it's working good but I don't want the $var0 till $var2 not static but dynamic because we will not be knowing the number of data present in the array. So how we can make it like all 0,1,2 in a variable inside the foreach...

Comment: ..but what variable to implode

Comment: You task seems completely strange now :) You WILL know the number of data in an array - you can always use `count($array)` to get the number of elements. But I've got question: why do you refuse to use associative array or just array for that?

Comment: And I've got the most important question: what your code is intendef for? :) I'm sure there are better ways to do that than the one offered above. Always use the simplest code.

Comment: implode on the actual array, having the ', ' as your glue parameter will do the same:
echo implode(', ', $my_array);

Comment: I know, that is in an updated unswer already. But if that was the purpose - everything else makes no sense :) I thought the intention was to have separate variables :)

Comment: Guys please give me sometime, I wanted to use your ideas and do some web research also... I ll login tomorrow until then i request you to wait.

Comment: kovpack - The main intention of the code is to store array values in different variables..

Comment: Kovapack -  Also your code returns parse error...`echo $var0,", ", $var1,", " $var2;` should be changed to -> `echo $var0.", ".$var1.", ".$var2;` I ll use assoc array when needed am just simulating and exercising the concept to apply it for a bigger tasks..

Comment: No, it should not be changed that way, `echo` can output a few variables at a time using `,` sign also. And there is no need to cancatenate strings. It is perfectly valid. I think something is wrong with your environment if that does not work on your machiene.

Answer (score 0):

it's a matter of the data you need to process...if it's pretty static, you don't need the second foreach() for example, since you compare the keys anyways...

```
foreach($datavalueas $resultdatakey=>$resultdatavalue){
    if($resultdatakey== 'A'){
    //stuff for a
    }
    if($resultdatakey== 'B'){
    //stuff for b
    }
}
```

would become

```
if(isset($datavalueas['A'])){
    //stuff for a
}
if(isset($datavalueas['B'])){
    //stuff for b
}
```

since the foreach uses copies of the array, which are pretty bad for the performance...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming i got your question right, you could use something like:

```
$array = array( 'x', 'y', 'z' );
foreach ($array as $name )
    $$name = rand(1,100);

var_dump($x);
```

the $$ is key here, the first $ implies the variable as the second $ is used as the identifier for the variable. In this case the value being iterated over in the array. Giving us 3 variables: $x, $y, $z.

-- edit:

the correct code, besides using extract():

```
<?php
    $my_array = array("hello","world","howareu");
    $c = count($my_array);

    for($i=0;$i < $c;$i++){
        $v = 'var'.$i;
        $$v = $my_array[$i];
    }

    echo "$var0, $var1, $var2";
?>
```

Comment: And ofcourse you can use an extra $i to make the name for the variable, instead of using the value in the array.

Comment: It is returning `Notice: Undefined variable: var0, var1 & var2 ` with printed `, ,` Also remember that, I would be needing like not directly or statically or hardcoded as $var0, $var1 and $var2 but `$var.$i`.

Comment: Remove the $ from the $v = '$var'.$i; I forgot it in my supplied code.

Comment: Then repost your updated code, it is compiling and working as expected if i run my code. The code of kovpack is now exactly the same as mine btw:)

Answer (score 0):

You can create dynamic variables via variables variable as Mr.kovpack have stated here. In below code you can access the variables from 0 to $c-1(count of array) as per your comment to Mr.kovpack.

```
$my_array = array("hello","world","howareu");
    $c = count($my_array);

    for($i=0;$i<=$c-1;$i++){
        ${'var'.$i} = $my_array[$i]; //Dynamic variable creation
//        $splited = list($v) = $my_array;
    }
echo $var0.$var1.$var2;
```

or you could use like below:

```
$my_array = array("hello","world","howareu");
    $c = count($my_array);

    for($i=0;$i<=$c-1;$i++){
        $a='var'.$i;
        $$a = $my_array[$i];
    }
echo $var0."-".$var1."-".$var2;
```

You can read more on it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)